# ARIA: How to expand flat partial list?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Imagine I have a flat list that is too long, so I will show only a few items and "last item" is "more button".
Any hints on how to make it accessible for people with readers and also not affect SEO?

Because list is flat, there is no option with expandable nested nodes https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_the_WAI-ARIA_aria-expanded_state_to_mark_expandable_and_collapsible_regions#Example_2:_Collapsing_and_expanding_subtrees_of_a_tree

I don't want to split the list into two independent blocks with lists and break continuity.

Example:

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
<li><button type="button">Show more</button></li>
<li hidden>Item 6</li>
<li hidden>Item 7</li>
<li hidden>Item 8</li>
<li hidden>Item 9</li>
...
</ul>
```

After clicking on Show more button, hidden items will be shown and button removed from DOM.

Any simple ideas? I have yet only complex ideas which is not ideal.

**EDIT 2021-09-08**

I thought about it and I think it is able to do it in a different way. Make all list items accessible for assistive technologies and visible for SEO.

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
<li role="none" aria-hidden="true"><button type="button">Show more</button></li>
<li class="clip-hidden">Item 6</li>
<li class="clip-hidden">Item 7</li>
<li class="clip-hidden">Item 8</li>
<li class="clip-hidden">Item 9</li>
...
</ul>
```

Button `onClick` event will remove the whole `<li>` with `role="none"`. Tab index will stay in the area, so if `<a>` is a child of `<li>`, then the next item will be focused on user action.

Is there any potential issues with role="none"/aria-hidden="true" for UL in assestive technologies/SEO?

Comment: Your second example would break accessibility.  The "show more" button would still be keyboard accessible so a screen reader can still TAB to it but since it's contained in an `aria-hidden` element, nothing will be announced for that button.  The user will be totally confused that the screen reader is silent.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, search engines are nowadays trying to base their rating on what users will perceive. If users click on a search result promising "Item 6", and then they don't see this item, they would turn around and perceive the search result as misleading. Hence, **hidden contents are generally rated lower or not at all, and you will affect SEO by hiding items**.

I do not have insights into how Google currently would be able to determine expandable contents, but your chances are definitely better when you are doing it in an accessible way:

If you stick to the idea of hiding these contents, I believe the best option here would be to apply the [disclosure pattern (show/hide)](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#disclosure) and to not remove the button.

If you do remove the button, you at least need to set focus either on the list, or on the first new list item, to ensure the user doesn't lose context.

```html
<li>Item 5</li>
<li tabindex="-1" id="item6">Item 6</li>
```

```js
button.onclick = () => { showMore(); item6.focus() }
```

One function of lists like `<ul>` is to tell screen reader users the total number of items in this list. Since you change this number on button click, it might be useful to add an accessible name to the list, which announces the total number like `<ul aria-label="9 items">` or the like.

Generally it would be good for usability if you would tell the user how many items they can expect before clicking on the button.

```
<button aria-expanded="false">Show 4 more</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input.
I thought about it more. To make it accessible and also visible SEO.

Maybe make all list items accessible and visible for assistive technologies and SEO.
Something like define role="none" / aria-hidden="true" for LI where is button. This will be visible for majority. UI will be visible and accessible by mouse or keyboard.
Rest list items will be only visually hidden with CSS clip directive. After click on button, all items will be in normal state and button will be removed/hidden.